# unable to open http, but can open ftp on debian server

Tags: linux, debian, firewall, http

I can reach my files via ftp, but can't open my website by domain name or ip. I get the following error:

> ERROR
>       The requested URL could not be retrieved (111) connection refused

I'm very new to linux/debian, so I hope i provide you the right information. These are the `netstat -lnp | grep 80` results to see if the server is listening to port 80:

```
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     30287    1680/gvfsd-burn     @/dbus-vfs-daemon/socket-cQlXqXvj
```

And the `iptables -L -vn` to see if the ports are open:

```
PKTS bytes target    prot     in     out     source        destination
951 44836 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0     0.0.0.0/0            
    tcp dpt:80
58  2548 ACCEPT      tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0     0.0.0.0/0            
    tcp dpt:443
0   0 ACCEPT         tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0     0.0.0.0/0            
    state NEW tcp dpt:443
```

There's no in/out and source/destination, so I guess there's something wrong with these ports. I'm not sure where to start solving this problem, I hope you can provide me more information.

Comment: To guess wethever the problem is due to network or webserver, try accessing your websiste from the server. eg telnet 127.0.0.1 80 or wget http://127.0.0.1/path or curl ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first test shows that apache is not started (it only shows a non-related connection from a unix stream). A typical output would be something like:

```
tcp6   0   0 ::::80  :::*   LISTEN
```

Maybe it has a startup error. Check the apache logs `/var/log/apache2/error.log` to search for misconfigurations or startup errors.

Try to start again the apache2 service `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart` and see if the console shows any warning or error message.